# i want this program to print the numbers in triangle shape

Tags: loops, numbers, geometry

i want to put spaces before the numbers to get the triangles shape !

```
package Za1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Za1 {



    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
 int i=-1;
 for (int j=0;j<11;j+=2){
  i++;
  for (int z=0;z<=j;z++){
      System.out.printf("%d",i);
      
  }System.out.println();
}
}

 }
```

pleaaaasse help me now !

Comment: Please do your own homework now! Or be more explicit about what the problem is and what you've tried to do to solve it.

Comment: you do not need to add spaces if you want to make a piramid,
since you didnt say that the top has to show on top, you could build the piramid that is pointing to the right side , that way you wont need any spaces :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Just small change in your code-

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = -1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j += 2) {
        i++;
        for (int k = i; k < 5; k++) //small change
            System.out.print(" "); //small change
        for (int z = 0; z <= j; z++) {
            System.out.printf("%d", i);

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```